# WPF DataGrid Update Column Value on Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid where one column contains an autocomplete box that, when an account number is entered, it should update the description in the next column. For the life of me I can’t get it to work. I’m able to make a selection in the autocomplete box and it updates the bound object but the description is never updated. I’m using (or at least trying to use) INotifyPropertyChanged (via PropertyChanged.Fody) on the parent and child models and the ViewModel but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly. The bindings seem to be working, but I think the problem is that when a selection is made in the autoselect, the account number property is changed on the Row, but no actual association is made between the Row and an Account object. Since no association is made the description is still blank. That's my theory at least. How can I get the description field to update properly?

This is how the Parent and Child are setup.

This is the parent model:

```
public class Transaction : RealmObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // PropertyChanged.Fody
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // For Realm
    public string ReportBasis { get; set; } 
    public string ReportName { get; set; } 
    public DateTimeOffset StartPeriod { get; set; } 
    public DateTimeOffset EndPeriod { get; set; } 
    public DateTimeOffset RunTime { get; set; } 

    public IList<TransactionDetails> Rows { get; }
}
```

And this is the Child:

```
public class TransactionDetails : RealmObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // For Realm
    public Account Account { get; set; } 
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public double? DebitAmount { get; set; }
    public double? CreditAmount { get; set; }
    public TransactionDetails()
    {
        this.Account = new Account() { RawAccountNumber = "", AccountKey = "", Description = "" };
    }
}
```

And this is the Account object

```
public class Account : RealmObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string AccountKey { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string RawAccountNumber { get; set; } //110100000
    public string FormattedAccountNumber { get; set; } // 1101-00-00
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel has a single Transaction

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private Transaction _transaction;
    public Transaction Transaction
    {
        get { return _transaction; }
        set {
            _transaction = value;
        }
    }
    ... 
    private async void GetTransactions()
    {
        var qb = new QB();
        Transaction = await qb.GetTransactions( StartDate, EndDate );
    }
    ...
}
```

the rows of which are bound to the DataGrid via Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TransactionsGrid" 
              DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,51,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Height="540"
              Width="902" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Transaction.Rows}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>      
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Account Number" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" 
                                     Text="{Binding Account.RawAccountNumber}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox
                                Background="AliceBlue"
                                IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                FilterMode="Contains"
                                MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                ValueMemberPath="RawAccountNumber"
                                PreviewTextInput="AutoCompleteBox_PreviewTextInput"
                                Text="{Binding Account.RawAccountNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Accounts}" >
                                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RawAccountNumber}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Description" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Account.Description}" IsReadOnly="True" /> <!-- This should update when the account is selected in the autocomplete box above -->
            <Controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Debit" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding DebitAmount, Mode=TwoWay }" Minimum="0" StringFormat="{}{0:C}" />
            <Controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Credit" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding CreditAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0" StringFormat="{}{0:C}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>            
    </DataGrid>
```

I'm fumbling my way through this. Can someone please take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where do you raise `PropertyChanged` when the value of `Transaction` changes, or when any of the properties of `Account` or `TransactionDetails` change?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was under the impression that this was handled by PropertyChanged.Fody. Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: @mack Ah, thank you. I haven't used PropertyChanged.Fody, but tou could rule out (or in) any problems with that by adding a handler to the viewmodel's `PropertyChanged` event to confirm that it's being raised properly.

Comment: Where are you setting the Description property, what value do you expect to see and when?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the "Account Description" column change when a selection is made in the autocomplete box. The description property is set when the Account object is created. My autocomplete box shows the description and the account number when activated so I know the description isn't blank.